# The two sides of a side-by-side markdown diff are overlapping each other

Tags: bug, design, beta-sites, diff

Time for a super-ultra-trivial bug: if you look at [diff #7 for this post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/593/revisions) on meta.Anime.SE, you see this (on Chrome 34 / Windows 7):

[image]

The deleted whitespace on the left side of the diff is slightly overlapping the right side of the diff.

Comment: Is that 6 to 8 pixels?

Comment: @rene By Jove, you've got it! It's sticking out of the left side of the diff by 8 pixels on the dot!

Comment: I think this is a bug with Chrome's handling of `white-space: pre-wrap`; it doesn't seem to be correctly wrapping whitespace at the end of a line, leading to the overflow behavior you observe. FWIW, Firefox does not exhibit this behavior.