# Image overlapping in Review Side-by-Side view

Tags: bug, review, design

In reviewing a post in the reopen queue, I came across the following.

> [image: Review with overlapping side-by-side view]

(The review in question is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/39963))

I don't see anything jumping out at me as a cause, so it could be browser related (just a wild guess though)

Browser: Chrome 43.0.2357.132 m
OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: DO YOU SEE what happens when you let the small problems [slide by unfixed???!?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232136/244519) lol .... meta.SO dup http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276670/review-queue-side-by-side-diff-broken-when-wide-image

Comment: This is due to the CSS, not a browser issue.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/46816) as well. It should be an easy fix; the problem seems to be that the side-by-side column is limited to 330 pixels:

[image]

but there is a `max-width: 410px` for images in the side-by-side column, inflating the image over the column boundary:

[image]

Disabling this rule produces the desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

(from [my MSO dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341819/layout-bug-in-the-side-by-side-view-in-review))

Adjusting the CSS (across a couple files) to the following would give more room without expanding the standard 1060px column everything sits in. And I can't imagine an issue with the sidebar text overflowing, as the values below are about as wide as they would ever be:

```css
#mainbar, .mainbar { /* all.css */
    #width: 850px;
}
#revisions .sidebyside-diff > div { /* this style is set inline */
    width: 395px !important;
}
#sidebar, .sidebar { /* all.css */
    width: 200px;
}
```

I like this solution a bit better than Glorfindel's because, instead of shrinking the image to fit, it expands the side-by-side columns to better utilize the space in the existing 1060px column that all site content sits within already.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed at some point:

[image: side-by-side diff with non-overlapping images]

The relevant names for the CSS have changed in the interim - here's screenshots of the relevant parts of my browser console for [deleted images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C42lz.png) and for [added images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAFij.png). In summary, the classes applied to the images (`diff-delete` and `diff-add`) no longer affect width at all. However, since the images are inside a `div` with the `s-prose` class, and `.s-prose img` applies `max-width: 100%`, they end up simply scaling nicely with their diff's half of the screen.